# combinng two values in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

How do I combine two values in a column? I am using a left outer jon from two tables and the partner column has duplicates as shown. Thanks for any help.

Partner: a a b b

Name:1 1 1 1

into

partner: a a

name:11

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have duplicate columns, rows, or values?

Comment: I just have duplicate variables in one column that equal the same value in the name column. I am gonna try Union All though

Comment: ok, i changed my answer now that I understand...  in the UNION select the 2 different columns but name them the same..  so you'd have 2 SELECT statements loading from the same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UNION to make a dervied table, then `GROUP` or `DISTINCT` the results, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COL1
FROM (
SELECT P.PARTNER AS COL1
FROM TABLE AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT P.Name AS COL1
FROM TABLE AS P
) AS C
```

What matters is that in both `SELECT` statements the column names and types are the same.